# Create LocalDB for testing from Visual Studio SQL project

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, integration-testing

I'm trying to create an integration tests for my project. I need to test a controller that makes call to stored procedure through repository. An empty database should be created on each runs of certain scope of tests. So I'm going to implement the following steps:

1. Create **LocalDB**
2. Run some Pre-scripts(to add test data)
3. Run test
4. Run some Post-scripts (if needed to run other test on this database)
5. Remove **LocalDB**

In my solution I have `.sqlproj` with all tables and SPs. How can I create **LocalDB** with the same structure as in `.sqlproj` from  C# code? Or how can I generate the script with all objects to run it on **LocalDB**?

In bin folder of `.sqlproj` exists **MyProjectName_Create.sql** but it doesn't run in `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

P.S. Related question is [How to disable predeployment and postdeployment scripts in DacServices.Deploy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022266/how-to-disable-predeployment-and-postdeployment-scripts-in-dacservices-deploy)

Comment: do you create an empty database in MyProjectName_Create.sql ?

Answer (score 1):

In the build folder of your sqlproj you can also find [DBName].dacpac file. You can use sqlpackage.exe to deploy the dacpac to your localdb. Ben Day explains in [this blog](https://www.benday.com/2012/12/18/deploy-a-sql-server-database-projects-dacpac-with-sqlpackage-exe/) pretty nicely. You can find sqlpackage.exe in your sql server installation folder if it is not directly available from the command line.

```
SqlPackage /Action:Publish 
   /SourceFile:”Benday.SampleApp.Database.dacpac”
   /TargetDatabaseName:BendaySampleAppDb 
   /TargetServerName:”demo2012util”
```